# Add migration Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, migration, dbcontext

I want to migrate a DAL with a `DbContext` to create the database.

However when I type the following in package manager console, and the selected project is the DAL:

```
add-migration initial -verbose
```

I get

> build started
> build succeeded

and then the exception

> Add migration Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

So far I have reinstalled VS2019 Enterprise to no avail.

I'm now installing a specific earlier build but don't know why the error is showing.

On my desktop PC, I can run `add-migrate initial -verbose` just fine, and that's version VS2019 16.11.7

I don't know why my laptop is giving me such error.

Is it a system variable that I need to adjust or has anyone had this particular error and knows what to do?

Thanks in advance if you can help me out.

Comment: Try running `dotnet ef migrations add`

Comment: you can close this topic, I found my mistake.
you have to go to advanced systemsettings in configuration , select environment variables, and select path , and move "dotnet" all the way up at Path
Then you have to delete ef core packages in .nuget folder under c:\users{username}.nuget
Then you have to delete ef core nuget packages and reinstall them (i used 3.1.1 for ef core, design, tools, sqlserver), rebuild project in Visual Studio, then redo add-migration initial -verbose in package manager console and it should work