# Add-Migration throws Win32Exception in VS Community 2022

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022

I have a simple WebAPI project (.NET 6) using VS Community 2022 and I'm trying to add a migration in package manager console with the following command:

```
add-migration initial
```

which leads to the following error:

```
add-migration : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): 

"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."
   At line:1 char:1
 + add-migration initial
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo  : NotSpecified: (:) 
       [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception,Add-Migration
```

- The exact same code runs on VS Community 2019 (.NET 5) without any issues, so I don't think it has anything to do with the code.
- Even an empty WebAPI project in VS 2022 (with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package installed) throws the same Win32Exception.
- On the other hand, in VS 2019, the empty WebAPI project (with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package installed) gives the "No DbContext was found" error, which is expected.
- I've also tried reinstalling the packages and restarting visual studio and it didn't work. I'd appreciate your help!

I have installed the following NuGet Packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040512/add-migration-exception-calling-start-with-1-arguments-the-specified-exe

Comment: @stuartd No. I've already tried that one.

Comment: Why didn’t you add that to your question, then? ‘What you’ve tried already’ is essential information,

Comment: Does adding `-Verbose` give any additional information?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are facing this issue when you trying to scafolding database constraints for that while writing the connection string. Replace `"\\"` with `"\"`

Example:- `Local\\database` should be `Local\database`