# Entity Framework Core unable to add migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Every time I Attempted to create a migration I am presented with the below error in Package Manager Console:

PM> Add-migration Initial
Build started...

Build succeeded.

Add-migration : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."
At line:1 char:1

- Add-migration Initial
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception,Add-Migration
  ```

adding -verbose gives me no further info.

Anyone got any idea on some of the common fixes for this?

Thanks

Comment: [Would you mind re-editing the environment and testing again?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70040512/7687666)

Comment: `-Verbose` should tell you what executable it's trying to start. Can you add the full output?